# Linphone: Type UnsafePointer<MSList> does not conform to protocol Sequence

Tags: ios, loops, call, voip, linphone

I am trying to loop through all calls in Linphone and find out the status for each call but I am unable to loop through the MSList.

This is the code I am trying:

```
for call in linphone_core_get_calls(lc) {

        }
```

This is the error it gives:
Type 'UnsafePointer!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional>') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following ways:

```
let calls = linphone_core_get_calls(lc)

for index in 0..<ms_list_size(calls) {
    // MSList is a struct, data is a generic field containing what you need
    let data = ms_list_nth_data(calls, index)

    // bind the memory to the type you need
    // or just do what you need here
}
```

You can also use the `forEach` method with a C callback of type `MSIterateFunc`

```
ms_list_for_each(calls) { element in 
    let element = element?.bindMemory(to: MSList.self, capacity: 1)
    let data = element?.pointee.data

    // bind the memory to the type you need
    // or just do what you need here
}
```

There are other `ms_list_*` methods you should check to achieve what you need. Be careful when working with `MSList` as you work directly with `UnsfafePointers`.